# How to execute sql function in hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, function

I have a sql function (not procedure) with input params and output result returned, which can be called through the `select function(:param) from dual`. But I need to call it not through the select. The question is how to do this from Hibernate like this

```
begin function(:param); end;
```

Answer (score 0):

so solution is 
1) `session.beginTransaction();`
2) `session.createNativeQuery("declare res; begin res := function(:param); end;")`
3) `query.executeUpdate();`